# Is "Aloud Reading"correct?

Tags: sentence-structure, adverbs

I was about to read a term paper written by a non-native student of English comparing between two types of reading. Then I noticed that the author started the title with ("Aloud Reading" and Silent Reading). I am wondering why he used " Aloud Reading" instead of the more correct " Reading Aloud". Is the position of the adverb " Aloud" here correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a highly unusual way of expressing the idea. In short, the use of *aloud* in the title is not normal.

It's more natural to think of a word that precedes *reading* to be an adjective and a word that follows *reading* to be an adverb. In other words, depending on its position in the phrase, *reading* is either a noun or a verb.

It makes more sense if you expand the phrases into actual sentences.

Noun and adjective:

> It was **a** reading.
>
> ✔ It was **a** *silent* reading.
>   ✘ It was **an** *aloud* reading.

Here, reading is an event. It uses an article in front of it and is used as a noun. The modifying words in front of *reading* are adjectives.

However, we simply don't say an *aloud reading*. It's meaning is understood, but we don't express it that way.

More natural would be something like:

> ✔ It was **a** *vocal* reading.

Although this sounds a bit odd on its own, it makes sense when contrasted with a silent reading.

---

Verb and adverb:

> I was reading.
>
> ✔ I was reading *silently*.
>   ✔ I was reading *aloud*.

Here, reading is an actual verb that doesn't use an article in front of it. The modifying words that follow it are adverbs.

Note, too, that while adverbs normally take an *-ly* form, in this particular case, we have the flat adverb *aloud* that is acceptable. There is no such adverb as *aloudly*. (There is *loudly*, but that would be contrasted with *quietly*, which doesn't quite apply in this case.)

---

In the title of the paper, the complete sentences have been pared down to just phrases, but one of them is used in a way that is unnatural.

To maintain parallelism, and to use commonly acceptable phrases, it should really have been titled as one of the following:

> Vocal Reading and Silent Reading
>   Reading Aloud and Reading Silently

Comment: I really appreciate your reply.